# How to show selected value in dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

After submission of JSP page request goes to servlet. In the servlet I have requirement like need to send the an object to same JSP page to fill the form text fields and dropdown lists.

User will enter id value in the form and we need to fetch the data from database and need to fill the rest of the fields in the same page

**Initially when JSP page is loaded dropdown list values should be fetched from the database**

Issue:

how to show fetched value from the database in the dropdown list box after submission.

because it is conflicting  with earlier scenario(get values dynamically from database while loading) !!

```
  /*

      <sql:setDataSource driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
                   url="jdbc:odbc:lab"
                   var="localSource" 
                   />

<sql:query dataSource="${localSource}" 
           sql="select cate_id,cate_desc from category"
           var="result" />
  <select name="cate_id">
  <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="r">
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${r.cate_id eq a }"> // I got a value from request.getattribute
        <option value="${r.cate_id}" selected="selected">${r.cate_desc}</option>
        </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <option value="${r.cate_id}">${r.cate_desc}</option>
   </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
   </c:forEach>
   </select>
```

*/

Issue

it is showing values from database in checkbox as it should but after submitting the form

page not showing selected value by user in checkbox.(showing all values)

Please help me out

Comment: is the issue with your requirment or with your code? If it's with the requirement ask some clarification to your product owner, if it's with the code please post some fragment and explain what is not working

Comment: It is not high level project requirement :)
My college assignment.
If you understand my problem Please do suggest some solution.

Guide me to show fetched value from the database in the dropdown list box.

Comment: The solution to your problem is: do 1 query to get the values, then iterate over the `ResultSet` in your jsp and generate the html accordingly. I don't know which technologies you are using for the db access (JDBC, Hibernate etc...) nor the tables that you are using so I can't be more helpful than this. Please, write down some code and if it doesn't work post it and somebody will help you troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Initially when JSP page is loaded dropdown list values should be fetched from the database

First create a POJO class to hold all form information in one place like:

```
public class UserFormDTO {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String selectedOption;
   private List<String> options;

   public UserFormDTO(){}

   //getters and setters
}
```

on form submit in servlet `doPost()`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    //build UserFormDTO instance form user filled fields
    //store UserFormDTO in database here.. 
}
```

retrieve UserFormDTO instance from from database in `doGet()` of servlet and add it in request to use in jsp like:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                           throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Retrieve UserFormDTO instance from database

    //add it to request
    request.setAttribute("userFormDTO", userFormDTO);

    //forward to jsp
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("userForm.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

in jsp render form using [jstl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) jsp:

add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

in top of jsp then,
**to show selected value in dropdown list**
 render form like:

```
<form action="someAction" method="post">
    id:
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    Options:
    <select name="selectedOption">
    <c:forEach items="${userFormDTO.options}" var="opt">
       <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${opt eq userFormDTO.selectedOption}">
            <option value="${opt}" selected="selected">${opt}</option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <option value="${opt}">${opt}</option>
        </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

**Note:**
 jstl.jar should be available in CLASSPATH in order to use `<c:tag..`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
I'm working on it and will let you know

Comment: @NareshSathu ok, when you face any problem let me know, and don't forget to tick as answer if it helped you!

Comment: small bug in my code.
Please help me to find what is wrong

Comment: @NareshSathu what it is? you can ask a new question.

Comment: @NareshSathu what you mean by **page not showing selected value by user in checkbox** make little it clear, i am not getting you.

Comment: Sorry for that "CHECKBOX".
I have to pull the value from db for specific user and have to show it in dropdownlist

Comment: k, what about your problem is solved? or having any problems? please use a servlets and POJO classes to make use of **OO concept**, JAVA is a OOP language respect it. your developing style is bad, don't keep database access and business logic's in jsp page. i have clearly mentioned in answer.